# Why won't SQL Server CE load?

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-ce

I installed SQL Server Compact 3.5 on Windows 7 (it was installed first before IIS, but I've re-installed it after IIS was running). I then made a virtual directory and configured it to access anonymously, and for the user I chose my Windows login. When I try to test the installation by loading "pcname/sqlce/sqlcesa35.dll" on a browser, it tries to load for a long time before I get a "timed out" message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have some tips here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2010/06/walkthrough-configuring-merge.html

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work-- once. But the next day it's the same problem again. I tried to repeat what I did yesterday but no go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by reinstalling, but got a 401.2 error. Fixed that by adding and configuring the IUSR user (default in the the Web Syn Wizard) to the sqlce virtual directory's permissions (done through IIS).